# Cannot install xUnit package

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nuget, xunit

My case is simple. I create an empty project, a class library. I go into the Package Manager and hit `Install-Package xunit`. Doesn't work.

However, for example `Newtonsoft.Json` does work. What is more, even the older version of `xunit` also works: `2.1.0-beta4-build3109`. The following version `2.1.0-rc1-build3168` seems to be adding a new package: `xunit.extensibility.execution 2.1.0-rc1-build3168` and it probably makes the entire process crash.

Please help, I have no idea what else I can do <3

```
Package Manager Console Host Version 3.2.0.10516

Type 'get-help NuGet' to see all available NuGet commands.

PM> Install-Package xunit
Attempting to gather dependencies information for package 'xunit.2.1.0' with respect to project 'Test', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'xunit.2.1.0' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving actions to install package 'xunit.2.1.0'
Resolved actions to install package 'xunit.2.1.0'
Removed package 'xunit.2.1.0-beta4-build3109' from 'packages.config'
Successfully uninstalled 'xunit.2.1.0-beta4-build3109' from Test
Removed package 'xunit.assert.2.1.0-beta4-build3109' from 'packages.config'
Successfully uninstalled 'xunit.assert.2.1.0-beta4-build3109' from Test
Removed package 'xunit.core.2.1.0-beta4-build3109' from 'packages.config'
Successfully uninstalled 'xunit.core.2.1.0-beta4-build3109' from Test
Removed package 'xunit.extensibility.core.2.1.0-beta4-build3109' from 'packages.config'
Successfully uninstalled 'xunit.extensibility.core.2.1.0-beta4-build3109' from Test
Adding package 'xunit.assert.2.1.0' to folder 'C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Test\packages'
Added package 'xunit.assert.2.1.0' to folder 'C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Test\packages'
Added package 'xunit.assert.2.1.0' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'xunit.assert 2.1.0' to Test
Adding package 'xunit.extensibility.core.2.1.0' to folder 'C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Test\packages'
Added package 'xunit.extensibility.core.2.1.0' to folder 'C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Test\packages'
Added package 'xunit.extensibility.core.2.1.0' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'xunit.extensibility.core 2.1.0' to Test
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'xunit.extensibility.execution 2.1.0' does not exist in project 'Test'
Removed package 'xunit.extensibility.core 2.1.0' from 'packages.config'
Removed package 'xunit.assert 2.1.0' from 'packages.config'
Package 'xunit.extensibility.core.2.1.0-beta4-build3109' already exists in folder 'C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Test\packages'
Added package 'xunit.extensibility.core.2.1.0-beta4-build3109' to 'packages.config'
Package 'xunit.core.2.1.0-beta4-build3109' already exists in folder 'C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Test\packages'
Added package 'xunit.core.2.1.0-beta4-build3109' to 'packages.config'
Package 'xunit.assert.2.1.0-beta4-build3109' already exists in folder 'C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Test\packages'
Added package 'xunit.assert.2.1.0-beta4-build3109' to 'packages.config'
Adding package 'xunit.2.1.0-beta4-build3109', which only has dependencies, to project 'Test'.
Package 'xunit.2.1.0-beta4-build3109' already exists in folder 'C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Test\packages'
Added package 'xunit.2.1.0-beta4-build3109' to 'packages.config'
Package 'xunit.extensibility.execution 2.1.0' does not exist in folder 'C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Test\packages'
Removing package 'xunit.extensibility.core 2.1.0' from folder 'C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Test\packages'
Removed package 'xunit.extensibility.core 2.1.0' from folder 'C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Test\packages'
Removing package 'xunit.assert 2.1.0' from folder 'C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Test\packages'
Removed package 'xunit.assert 2.1.0' from folder 'C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Test\packages'
Install-Package : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package xunit
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

PM>
```

Comment: I think this question should be asked in `Super User` instead of `stackoverflow`.

Comment: I would look at the $error.Exception.StackTrace and see if it is a known [NuGet 3 bug](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/). There are a few null reference bugs in NuGet 3 but without the callstack it is not obvious where it is failing.